# Fixing Some Kotlin Syntax

Tags: kotlin

I just finish built a simple android music app with Java, then I convert the java files to Kotlin with Kotlin plugin for Android Studio.

There are some error, in MainActivity.kt

```
private fun display() {

    val mySongs = findSong(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())
    items = arrayOf(mySongs.size.toString())


    for (i in mySongs.indices) {
        items[i] = mySongs[i].name.toString().replace(".mp3", "").replace(".wav", "")
    }

    val adp = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items!!)

    listView!!.adapter = adp
    listView!!.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, position, l -> startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, PlayerActivity::class.java).putExtra("pos", position).putExtra("songs", mySongs)) }
}
```

this line : `items[i] = mySongs[i].name.toString().replace(".mp3","").replace(".wav", "")`

showing an error: **Smart cast to 'Array' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time.**

and on the PlayerActivity.kt

```
val i = intent
val b = i.extras
mySongs = b.getParcelableArrayList<Parcelable>(mySongs.toString())
position = b.getInt("pos", 0)
val u = Uri.parse(mySongs!![position].toString())
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, u)
```

the `b.getParcelableArrayList<Parcelable>(mySongs.toString())` has a problem says Type mismatch.

Anyone can help me fix this? Thank You

Answer (score -1):

This line

```
items = arrayOf(mySongs.size.toString())
```

creates an array of 1 element containing a string with the size of my songs. ex: ["23"]

You could use this instead: `arrayOfNulls(mySongs.size)`

For the other question:

```
mySongs = b.getParcelableArrayList<Parcelable>(mySongs.toString())
```

should return the same type as (I assume that it was the same code than in main activity because they are in 2 differents files and the context of mySongs is not provided)

```
val mySongs = findSong(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())
```

mySongs will have be the same type as the result of findSong.

Also you should use var instead of val because val are immutable